# How to open all the folds containing a search pattern at the same time?

Tags: vim, folding

I have a file consisting in about a hundred paragraphs, each one being folded according to the third example under the :help fold-expr section, which makes a fold out of paragraphs separated by blank lines :

```
set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*$'&&getline(v:lnum+1)=~'\\S'?'<1':1
```

Suppose I launch a search pattern, e.g.

```
/Item 014
```

This pattern may be found in 7 of the different folds.

I know I could just press "n" 6 times to open successively all the folds concerned by the search.

But I would like to have the 7 folds opened in one move, in order to have a quick overview.

I tried a macro

```
qu n q
```

then

```
/Item 014
100@u
```

but failed.

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After having performed your search for `/Item 014`, you can use the following command to open all folds containing the pattern:

```
:g//foldopen
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the `:g` command reuses the last search pattern when left empty. The Ex command `:foldopen` is thus executed on all matching lines: it opens the fold on the current line.